# Ambiguous error in creating BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `Reservation` table and am creating a BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks whether a user's reservation is already in the database, i.e. prevent him from making duplicate reservations. This is done to signal the front-end that the user is unable to make a duplicate reservation.

However, mySQL raises this error: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`. For some reason when the body between `BEGIN` and `END` is empty, it doesn't raise an error.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    customer_user_id integer,
    date integer,
    time integer,
    name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT -- error raised in this line
ON reservation FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO sum 
    FROM reservation r
    WHERE (r.customer_user_id = new.customer_user_id)
    AND (r.date = new.date)
    AND (r.time = new.time);

    IF sum = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO reservation values (new.customer_user_id, new.date, new.time, new.name);
    ELSE 
        RAISE NOTICE 'duplicate'
    END IF;
END;
```

Additionally, could this trigger be a constraint on the table `Reservation`? E.g. `(customer_user_id, date, time) UNIQUE` of sorts, which would prevent adding of duplicates, but I am clueless on how to "signal" the front-end which in turn prompts the user that they cannot add a duplicate reservation. 
Sorry if some parts of the code might be weird, I'm new to SQL and was taught pSQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger..'INSERT INTO reservation values ' and RAISE NOTICE does not exist in mysql. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: Do you really have reservations for a point in time - usually they are for a range of datetime.

Comment: You don't say where you are running this code so you may need delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html